# How should I handle this Optimistic Concurrency error in this Entity Framework code, I have?

Tags: .net-4.0, repository-pattern, entity-framework-4, race-condition, optimistic-concurrency

I have the following pseduo code in some **Repository Pattern** project that uses **EF4**.

```
public void Delete(int someId)
{
   // 1. Load the entity for that Id. If there is none, then null.
   // 2. If entity != null, then DeleteObject(..);
}
```

Pretty simple but I'm getting a run-time error:-

> ConcurrencyException: Store, Update,
>   Insert or Delete statement affected an
>   unexpected number of rows (0).

Now, this is what is happening :-

1. Two instances of EF4 are running inthe app at the same time.
2. Instance A calls delete.
3. Instance B calls delete a nano second later.
4. Instance A loads the entity.
5. Instance B also loads the entity.
6. Instance A now deletes that entity - cool bananas.
7. Instance B tries to delete the entity, but it's already gone. As such, the no-count or what not is 0, when it expected 1 .. or something like that. Basically, it figured out that the item it is suppose to delete, didn't delete (because it happened a split sec ago).

I'm not sure if this is like a *race-condition* or something.

Anyways, is there any tricks I can do here so the 2nd call doesn't crash? I *could* make it into a stored procedure.. but I'm hoping to avoid that right now.

Any ideas? I'm wondering If it's possible to lock that row (and that row only) when the select is called ... forcing Instance B to wait until the row lock has been relased. By that time, the row is deleted, so when Instance B does it's select, the data is not there .. so it will never delete.

Comment: Why don't you just handle the concurrency exception? If the object has been deleted from another thread (aka EF instance) then no work remains for this thread since the record has already been deleted.

Comment: That's the problem -> both instances think they have an object to delete, because they both read from the DB at the same time. It's just that Instance A actually completes the DeleteObject(..) method a nano second before the second call .. for the same object. Now I an handle the exception .. but I feel like that is avoiding the real problem .. and i'm wondering if it could be handled with some locking or something?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would catch the OptimisticConcurrencyException and then handle the problem in a manner that makes sense for your business model - then call SaveChanges again.

```
try
{
    myContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException e)
{
    if (e.StateEntries.FirstOrDefault() is DeletingObject)
        myContext.Detach(e.StateEntries.First();
    myContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Give that a whirl and see how you get on - not tested/compiled or anything - I've used DeletingObject as the type of the entity you're trying to delete.  Substitute for your entity type.

Comment: Hmm - interesting. Can u actually explain what you are trying to do in the catch? So with my initial example, if Instance_B does the delete .. and it throws the exception .. then your trying to see detach .. the deleted object (because it shouldn't be there?)

Comment: By detaching the object that has already been deleted I am attempting to stop the state manager from pushing that delete operation to the database.  An object that should be deleted is still attached, it's got an entity state of deleted.  I've just run a quick test and calling .DeleteObject(myObject) followed by .Detach(myObject) followed by .SaveChanges() doesn't push the delete.  Give it a go mate and see if it helps.